# Can I create 1 self signed certficate for multiple servers if I don't have a FQDN?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl

I have a kubernetes cluster with 4 nodes hosting an application via nginx on my homelab with no FQDN but I'd like to use SSL for the web service with a self-signed certificate.  Can I create 1 self-signed wilcard certificate for a CIDR block (e.g. 10.10.10.0/24) or do I have to create 1 certificate for each server?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are using the cert for?

Comment: Encryption via HTTPS/SSL when accessing web services via browser.  I just want to implement security at different layers even though it's my home dev environment.

Comment: You can't do CIDR, or usefully do wildcard, but you can do [Subject Alternative Name (SAN)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.6) with one entry for each IPaddress; 4 should be easy, although say 64 would start to get tedious. There are many existing Qs (variously here superuser unix.SX security.SX and I think even SO) on creating selfsigned cert with SAN using openssl, and some on using Java keytool; if you want something else, maybe add to your Q.

Comment: As others have implied, a cert binds to a domain name, not an IP address.

Comment: SSL/TLS works based on credibility established through a domain, meaning that you can't prove who you are if you don't have one.  Although you can you a SAN as mentioned above as a sort of workaround.